# Passing react props as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find this syntax so weird.

```js
     <>
      {items.map((item, i) => {
        return <ItemComponent key={i} {...{ [resourceName]: item }} />;
      })}
    </>
```

Can you explain it please?
I know that in `Parent` component now I get `name` prop, but IDK how did this happen..

Comment: `...` is javascript, the spread operator. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax.

Comment: Is this code you're working on? It seems like a bad way to write a component.

Comment: Seems like it's not necessary, I think the equivalent is `name="Ahmed"`

Comment: @Andy I updated the snippet to the original one.

Comment: Its used this way to make a reusable list component and yes I understand the spread operator. 
But I dont know why do we put it into another object!

Comment: @Andy that would not be the same, this wouldn't work

Comment: @Apolo, you're right. I was distracted in the middle of making a sandwich.

Comment: @Andy have a good sandwich ! :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full context so here's my guess:

resourceName is a variable describing which prop will be set on ItemComponent.

you can't write `resourceName={item}` because then ItemComponent would have a property "resourceName" instead of whatever value is stored inside `resourceName`.

So the workaround for this is to create an object with only one key being the value of `resourceName` associated to the `item` object:

```js
const itemComponentProps = {
  [resourceName]: item;
};
```

---

If you are not familiar with this syntax, it's to use dynamic keys on objects.

example:

```js
const dynamicKey = 'foo';
const obj = {
  [dynamicKey]: 'bar'
}
console.log(obj[dynamicKey]); // bar
console.log(obj.foo); // bar
```

---

and you spread this object to the component:

```js
<ItemComponent key={i} {...itemComponentProps} />
```

Comment: {...itemComponentProps} 
Why do you spread it inside new object??
I mean wouldnt them be still inside an object??

Comment: the brackets around this is not to express an object but an expression to evaluate within jsx. Eg. you could have `key={i+2}`, the brackets represent a JS expression also here

Comment: Ohh, Got it :D Sorry :D